# How to compare element of two Pandas Data Frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframe of unequal length. I want to find the common indices and then compare the values of the element of a particular column  between two Dataframes

Answer (score 0):

```
    print(forecast.shape[0],df.shape[0])
    #468 448
   
    # Make forecast_truncated dataframe same as df dataframe
    forecast_truncated_index =forecast.index.intersection(df.index)
    forecast_truncated = forecast.loc[forecast_truncated_index]
    print(forecast_truncated.shape[0],df.shape[0])
    # Output 448 448

    # Do element wise comparision
    indices =m.history[m.history['y'] > forecast_truncated['yhat_upper']].index
    for index in indices:
        print("Values greater than threshold",m.history['y'][index],"--",m.history['ds'][index])
```

Note - I am new to Pandas, not sure if there is a more efficient way